# Assiging data to character array of a structure member using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

I was trying to experiment with structures and came up with a problem When I am,assign data to a character array of a structure member using  a pointer the compiler is throwing an error: "assignment to expression with array type". In my code I know that an array uses static memory allocation and pointer uses malloc for dynamic memory allocation. Can some body tell me how to resolve the issue.[Code for passing the structure pointer to a function to print the structure data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdeV6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In your example 'c' is an array of 20 bytes, so you could use strcpy:

```
    strcpy(struct_pointer->c, "hellos");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
struct_pointer->c="hellos"
```

actually tells compiler to do the following - allocate memory for string `"hellos"` plus null terminator and assign the pointer to this memory to `struct_pointer->c`, which is already allocated, thus compiler complaint is perfectly valid. In C you can't just assign a char array to another array, you need to use any type of memory copy function, for example

```
strcpy(struct_pointer->c, "hellos")
```

> In my code I know that an array uses static memory allocation and pointer uses malloc for dynamic memory allocation

It's not like that, in C you don't get automatic dynamic memory allocation unless you call `malloc` or its variants explicitly. Memory for `"hellos"` is also allocated on the stack

Answer (score -1):

Remember that "hellos" is not the same type with char[20], so you should try this:

```
strcpy(struct_pointer->c, "hellos");
```

instead of assignment a `const char*` to `char[20]` variable